# can anyone illustrate the return of "onOptionsItemSelected"?

Tags: android, return

in android development site, i saw the explanation of `onOptionsItemSelected`, on the `return` side, it said that:
`boolean Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, true to consume it here.`

Sorry for my dumb, can anyone illustrate what the sentence is explaining, should i return ***true*** or ***false*** in the normal situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should "android: onOptionsItemSelected" return true or false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719287/should-android-onoptionsitemselected-return-true-or-false)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should return true if you process the menu item and return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) if you don't.

e.g.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.option1:
            handleOption1();
            return true;
        case R.id.option2:
            handleOption2();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: But we also can return ```false``` instead, can't we?The documentation says that "The default implementation simply returns false to have the normal processing happen"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just let the system handle it by doing :

```
return super(...);
```

Else, the return TRUE/FALSE just means that if the case you are treating has fully handled the event just return TRUE. If thats not the case then return false, and system should be dispatching the even to the right handler.