# What should be returned, true or false for onOptionsItemSelected() ?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu

I was learning menu inflater and the tutorial I am following says we should return false in this function. However when I return true, I didn't notice any change or difference. So the question is:

- What should I return and why?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5719356/1300995

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the normal processing to happen, return false. Otherwise, return true.

See [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29).

By default, when you return false, Android calls the Runnable associated with the item or runs the Intent which you can set using `setIntent(...)` on the MenuItem. If you don't want this to happen, you should return true.

Say you create the MenuItem as follows.

```
MenuItem menu1 = new MenuItem(this);
menu1.setIntent(myIntent);
```

Here `myIntent` is what you want to do when the menu item is being clicked. For ex: say your menu item launches GMail app to send an email, with the text on a text view on your activity.

In your `onOptionsItemSelected()` callback, you can check the value of the text view, and return false if the text view is not empty (you have something in the text box, you can fire the `Intent` to GMail) otherwise show a message box saying "Please type a message first" and return true, so Android won't fire the Intent.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    if (textView.getText().trim().equals("")){
        // show the message dialog
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // we have some message. We can let android know that
        // it is safe to fire the intent.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...
Happy Coding.

Comment: can you please elaborate "Normal Processing"?

Comment: By default, when you return false, Android calls the `Runnable` associated with the item or runs the `Intent` which you can set using setIntent(...) on the MenuItem. If you don't want this to happen, ou should return true.

Comment: can you please elaborate with a little code? I am a noob so It is difficult for me to understand

Answer (score 5):

if you handle the event return true, otherwise return false