# Android menuitem onclick handler's return value

Tags: android, android-listview

In android when I define a menuitem's onclick handler in xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/context_menu"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/word_context_menu_title"
    android:onClick="deleteItem"/>
```

And in the corresponding activity I define a function deleteItem with the below signature.

```
public boolean deleteItem(MenuItem item){
    logger.info("delete button clicked");
    return false;
}
```

My question is what does the return value signify?  In which case should I return true and in which case should I return false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What the `boolean` return value means from the documentation of [onMenuItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener.html):

> Return true to consume this click and prevent others from executing.

So similar behaviour to `onOptionsItemSelected` with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719356/3286163). If I understand it correctly, this means that whenever you have successfully handled the event, you should return `true`.

---

Here's an example.

Say you have your `deleteItem` and also `onOptionsItemSelected`.

```
public boolean deleteItem(MenuItem item){
    Log.v("test", "delete button clicked");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.context_menu:
            Log.v("test","onOptionsItemSelected");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If you return `false` in `deleteItem` you will see that it is also handled in `onOptionsItemSelected`.

> >delete button clicked 
>   >onOptionsItemSelected

If you return `true` in `deleteItem` it will no longer be handled in `onOptionsItemSelected`.

> >delete button clicked

Also note that your `deleteItem` handle can be a `void` method and it will automatically return true as per the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/support/v7/internal/view/SupportMenuInflater.java#SupportMenuInflater.InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick%28android.view.MenuItem%29).